# Get the position of the selected row from ScrollPickerView ( a custom ui picker view for android )

Tags: android

I am developing in android and i have a requirement for making a custom ui picker view like the one in iphone for which i am using the code from the link

http://code.google.com/p/scroll-picker-view-for-android/

here in the

```
scrollPickerViewListener = this;
scrollPickerView = new ScrollPickerView(this);
scrollPickerView.addSlot(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.custom_list), 1, ScrollPickerView.ScrollType.Ranged);
scrollPickerView.setSlotIndex(0, 13);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new      
ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 200);
this.setContentView(scrollPickerView, params);
```

how to get the index of the selected item from the pickerview when the user scrolls

Answer (score 1):

I would first ask why you would want to create an iPhone picker instead of [using ones made for Android](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/pickers.html), anyways...

I checked some of the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/scroll-picker-view-for-android/source/browse/trunk/library/src/com/ttshrk/view/ScrollPickerView.java) of the library you are using and it seems that the developer of this library thought it was funny to leave absolutely no comments behind. It extends from a ListView so it shouldn't be that hard.

A quick glance shows a ScrollPickerViewListener. You should probably use that. Try this.

```
scrollPickerView.setScrollPickerViewListener(){
       public void onSingleTapUp(int index){

       }
}
```

Or...

```
@Override
public void onSingleTapUp(int slotId) {
   Toast.makeText(this, ""+slotId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I need to implement it because it is my app requirement anyways thanks for the post it is helpful